# How do I know how many flowers I have?

Tags: fable-3

Whenever I pick up a flower, it tells me how many I have in total, and how many of that color I have. Is there any way to know how many of each flower I have, without finding one to pick up? Sadly the map in the Sanctuary doesn't list the flowers in each zone like it does for keys, so there isn't even a way to know where to look for the remaining flowers.

I checked in the Stats area of the Sanctuary, but that was less than helpful as well.

Comment: They kind of dropped the ball on not including counts for the flowers and books in the map like they do for the gnomes and keys didn't they?

Comment: @Blake Yeah, definitely. Although you might be able to see which books you have in the library - not sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing this from memory as I don't have the game in front of me, but:

If you want to check which flowers and the amounts you have, return to the city of Aurora, enter the temple up the stairs and in there the priestess/queen is in a room where you give her the flowers. You should be able to see from there the colors and counts you have for each flower type I believe.

Comment: When you go to the temple, you can turn in any flowers that you've gotten all of. Sadly, there isn't any way to know how many of each flower you have. This is much better than not knowing at all, though. :)

Comment: Good answer.  I had one single flower left to get, and this answer helped me narrow it down to a single colour.  Many thanks.